# YAML just upload "part" without "urls"

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

Hey i have yaml code below and i want to add parts using python i.e. part-4,.... In doing so I only manage to create urls using the which I don't want.... can anyone help me? Current codeblock from python:

```
d = {'urls':{f'part-{i}': {'updated': 16662709610, 'url': 'http://any-do0main1.com/', 'url-name': f'crl{i}.der'}}
with open('test.yaml', 'a+') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(d, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

yaml:

```
urls:
  part-0:
    updated: 1666270610
    url: http://any-domain1.com/
    url-name: cr0.der
  part-1:
    updated: 1666270610
    url: http://crl.domain/
    url-name: crl1.der
  part-2:
    updated: 1666270900
    url: http://crl.swisssign.net/
    url-name: crl2.der
urls:
  part-3:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: cr3.der
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that you can append a YAML like a regular file. Here is a possible solution:

```
import yaml
import re

with open('test.yaml', 'r') as yaml_file_loaded:
    yaml_loaded = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file_loaded)  #load yaml
    part_keys = list(yaml_loaded['urls'].keys())  #get all part-# keys
    all_numbers = []
    for i in part_keys:  #parse all part+#
        all_numbers = all_numbers + re.findall(r'\d+',i) #get all # as str
    all_numbers = [int(i) for i in all_numbers]  # convert all # to int
    max_num = max(all_numbers)
    i = max_num + 1 # increment i with 1 from largest part-#
# d is modified arbitrarily.
d = {f'part-{i}': {'updated': 16662709610+i, 'url': f'http://any-do0maini{i}.com/', 'url-name': f'crl{i}.der'}}  # make the new entry
yaml_loaded["urls"].update(d)  # update with a new value. If same key, then replace

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(yaml_loaded, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)  # write new entry.
```

This code loads this

```
urls:
  part-0:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-1:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-2:
    updated: 16662709612
    url: http://any-do0maini2.com/
    url-name: crl2.der
```

and appends so it becomes:

```
urls:
  part-0:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-1:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-2:
    updated: 16662709612
    url: http://any-do0maini2.com/
    url-name: crl2.der
  part-3:
    updated: 16662709613
    url: http://any-do0maini3.com/
    url-name: crl3.der
```

**Furthermore...**

It handles also loading this one:

```
urls:
  part-0:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-1:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-2:
    updated: 16662709612
    url: http://any-do0maini2.com/
    url-name: crl2.der
  part-3341:
    updated: 16662709613
    url: http://any-do0maini3.com/
    url-name: crl3.der
```

and appends so it becomes:

```
urls:
  part-0:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-1:
    updated: 16662709610
    url: http://any-do0main1.com/
    url-name: crl0.der
  part-2:
    updated: 16662709612
    url: http://any-do0maini2.com/
    url-name: crl2.der
  part-3341:
    updated: 16662709613
    url: http://any-do0maini3.com/
    url-name: crl3.der
  part-3342:
    updated: 16662712952
    url: http://any-do0maini3342.com/
    url-name: crl3342.der
```